# jquery animation in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a one div that have relative position and ul into this that have absolute position.
want when click in right button ul shift to right and show next li child.
I have this code , this work in FF but in Chrome this don't work correctly.

In chrome when i press the button `UL` it will jump to the right and don't animate, and no show li

```
$(_rightNavigator).click(function () {
    $("#thumbviewer").stop().animate({
        left: '+=' + $("#thumbviewer li").outerWidth(true) + 'px'
    }, 1000);
});

.thumbviewer {position:absolute;padding:0 5px 0 0;margin:0;text-align:center;display:inline-block;}
.thumbviewer li{list-style:none;float:right;}
.thumbviewer li a {text-decoration:none;float:right;padding:4px 2px;margin:0;}
.thumbviewer li a img{border:2px solid #808080;border-radius:5px;}
```

Comment: Post a jsfiddle so people can have a look at a live example, you may get some more help then.